# GRUB not starting default system

Tags: grub2, 14.10, bootloader

My system doesn't boot until I press enter on grub.

```
cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="countdown"
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw init=/lib/systemd/systemd"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="1280x1024"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="0"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
```

Why isn't the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` setting working? I've ran `update-grub` and Grub Customizer, but nothing helps. My `os-prober` also isn't working. They both worked when i was on 14.04, now I'm using 14.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your actual `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, the one you've pasted isn't the "real" one.

Mine works to select a "default" entry (starts counting from zero) after 10 seconds with these lines:

```
set timeout=10
set default=0
```

Comment: I've done this, I'll see if it works on next boot. What reasons could there be for update-grub not making the file properly? I don't want to have to edit this file manually every time I update kernels. Also, os-prober is still not working.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use update-grub, I just know what the actual file should look like :-) And os-prober is a different problem, it's not part of the grub packages, not even a dependency. Making a new question about os-prober would be best, and if this grub default & timeout is solved you can mark this one as accepted / check-mark'ed

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="false"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
```

I find that nowadays simply removing `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` works the best. In short, replace above with just

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
```

and you should see the menu with 1 second timeout. If you want some other style, see `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` (run `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'` from command line because grub does not include sensible `man` pages).